How to get new cookies everytime from a password protected website?
I am trying to scrape a website that has APIs. One of the API gives json only if we are logged in.
I got logged in cookies and then send requests, I am successfully sending the request.
But the problem is that, those cookies expire after some time and I have to get new cookies to send the request.
Is there a way, that I can get fresh cookies automatically before scraping the website?
Note: I read somewhere that we can login manually using selenium and save cookies. These cookies are then used for scraping. But I do not know how to get cookies from selenium and use them for request library.
Can anyone help me out?
Link: https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/bewerberboerse/
I used requests library to login but instead of giving 302 response code, it either gave me 200 or 400.
Then I tried to use selenium but the structure of website is very complicated. There are too many redirections and elements are not being fetched successfully.

Why do you switch from Selenium to requests ?

Hm, you can use selenium to log in and then get cookies from selenium, by:
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
then return them and use them in your request, for example:
def convert_cookies_to_requests(cookies):
    session_cookies = {}
    for cookie in cookies:
        session_cookies[cookie['name']] = cookie['value']
    return session_cookies

